# Printing Unicode elements in a loop

Tags: python, unicode

Consider this:

```
print u'\u2599'
```

I get
    ▙
something like this, which is what I need

But when I try to run it in a loop like this :

```
for i in range(2500,2600):
    str1 = """u\'\\u""" + str(i) + '\''
    print str1
```

I just get an output like:

```
u'\u2500'
u'\u2501'
u'\u2502'
u'\u2503'
u'\u2504'
u'\u2505'
u'\u2506'
u'\u2507'
u'\u2508'
u'\u2509'
u'\u2510'
u'\u2511'
u'\u2512'
u'\u2513'
u'\u2514'
```

How do I get the code to print the Unicode values correctly in a loop?

I tried capturing the print output from the cmd prompt but it displays an error:

```
Unable to initialize device PRN
```

(which I researched and is probably because of the print command).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing *literal syntax* and the value it produces. You cannot produce a value and expect it to be treated as a literal, the same way that producing a string with `'1' + '0'` does not make the integer `10`.

Use the [`unichr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) to convert an integer to a Unicode character, or use the `unicode_escape` codec to decode a bytestring containing Python literal syntax to a Unicode string:

```
>>> unichr(0x2599)
u'\u2599'
>>> print unichr(0x2599)
▙
>>> print '\\u2599'
\u2599
>>> print '\\u2599'.decode('unicode_escape')
▙
```

You are also missing the crucial detail that the `\uhhhh` syntax uses **hexadecimal** numbers. `2500` decimal is `9C4` in hexadecimal, and `2500` in hexadecimal is 9472 in decimal.

To produce your range of values then, you want to use the `0xhhhh` Python literal notation to produce a sequence between 0x2500 hex and 0x2600 hex:

```
for codepoint in range(0x2500, 0x2600):
    print unichr(codepoint)
```

as that's easier to read and understand when using Unicode codepoints.

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth are you doing it like that?

If you're trying to print the code-points in that range you should do this:

```
for i in range(0x2500,0x2600):
    print unichr(i)
```

All you're doing in your code above is constructing a string with literal "\u" in it and a number ...

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; it was certainly correct enough if not addressing the other faults in the post.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0x2500, 0x2600):
    print unichr(i)
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; it was certainly correct enough if not addressing the other faults in the post. At least this post addressed the hexadecimal issues. An explanation as to what changed would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: for i in range(2500,2503):
    a="\\u"+str(i)
    print a.decode('unicode-escape')
   ...:     
─
━
│
```